# Data refresh issues when querying remote tables

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, oracle10g

Suppose to have two different Oracle databases, A and B, linked by a dblink from A to B.

On database A there is a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE LOCAL_TABLE (
    TAB_PK NUMBER(3) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR2(10)
);
```

And on database B we have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE REMOTE_TABLE (
    TAB_PK NUMBER(3) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    LOCAL_TABLE_FK NUMBER(3),
    QUANTITY NUMBER(3)
);
```

The above tables are clearly oversimplified and maybe not entirely accurate, but should allow to reproduce the issue I am experiencing.

Both table A and table B are populated by many client apps that insert related data in each of them.

Now suppose to have a view like this one on database A:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW LINKING_VIEW AS
SELECT
    L.TAB_PK,
    L.NAME,
    R.QUANTITY
FROM 
    LOCAL_TABLE L INNER JOIN REMOTE_TABLE@REMOTE_DB R ON L.TAB_PK = R.LOCAL_TABLE_FK
```

This view is queried by the code of my WCF service that exposes two methdos:

- UpdateQuantity (that updates quantity for a set of rows on table B)
- QueryView (that returns the view content)

Well what I am experiencing is that when I call UpdateQuantity and then QueryView most of the times I don't get the updated quantity on the first call, but only on succesive calls or after some time is passed.

I don't post any application code because I don't think the problem is in the application code. I managed to to reproduce the issue updating the table and querying the view with SQLDeveloper or Toad.

Any suggested solution beside putting both tables in the same database?

Comment: How are the two tables kept in sync?

Comment: I don't entirely understand the question. Let's say that there is a client app that inserts related rows in both tables. What sync methodology do you think about?

Comment: Something in the DB? Materialized views, Golden Gate/other data transfer products, scheduled jobs over a DB link, scheduled jobs over JDBC, file transfer (shudder) etc etc.

Comment: None of the above as far as I know. Should I be worried? ;-)

Comment: Not if you're keeping them inserting into both in the application. But, there's a reason why they don't have the same data. The tables existing isn't enough to ensure that they are the same (which is what you seem to expect (?)) so you have to ensure that you're performing identical operations at identical times in the app to ensure that they're the same (if you're not using some other method of replication),

Comment: I'll edit the question to provide more context